# Wait for text to appear on the screen espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso

I'm doing automation with Espresso, and on a screen I have to wait for a text to be displayed in a view as long as this text does not appear the test can not close. Is there any espresso method that performs this function?

Answer (score 0):

You can try Espresso Idling resource. You can listen for Async task in your app code, and communicate back with Espresso to notify that the task is completed.

Try https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/idling-resource